# how to enable a login box for all websites

Tags: debian, webserver

I got a development server which is open to the whole wide world.
So I want to secure it more by giving `.htaccess` logins to every user except those who are in a valid IP.

I know what to put in the `.htaccess` so it will work on individual sites. But I don't want to add that for 20+ sites.
So which file should I put the code to do apply it on all users/sites? All sites can have 1 login.

And after that how do I exclude 1 user/folder/domain, which has customer previews. On these Sites I want unique logins per client. Can I just override it with a `.htaccess` in the website `public_html` folder?

I have full root access, the server run's on debian and has directadmin

Can anybody help me on my way?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same directives you use in `.htaccess` files in your httpd.conf, you just need to place them in the `<Directory>` section, probably the one that deals with your webroot.

If you want to make use of an `.htaccess` file in a specific directory, you can either use `AllowOverride AuthConfig` everywhere (so that you can add users per directory/site if you chose), or specifically for that directory in your httpd.conf.